# How do I efficiently insert select and update data to a database using psychopg2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have some code that inserts some data into my database from a csv file. Right now it is running pretty slowly. I looked elsewhere and it seemed that using COPY may help speeding up my inserts, but(as you can see below), I need to sometimes update the db instead, since I don't want duplicates. Additionally, pretty much  all of the data relies on SELECT sub-queries. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
 def insert_values(self):
    read_dict=self.my_csv_reader.main_row_dict
    for key in read_dict:
        for row_index in range(1, len(read_dict[key])):
            if read_dict[key][row_index]==None or read_dict[key][row_index]=="" or read_dict[key][row_index]==" ":
                continue
            else:
                self.cur.execute(self.build_sub_select_query(self.ID, "wf_variable", "name = " + "'" + self.get_header_value(row_index) + "'"))
                wf_variable_id=self.cur.fetchall()[self.QUERY_LIST_INDEX][self.QUERY_TUPLE_INDEX]
                self.cur.execute(self.build_sub_select_query(self.ID, "point", "guid =" + "'" + read_dict[key][0] + "'"))
                point_id =self.cur.fetchall()[self.QUERY_LIST_INDEX][self.QUERY_TUPLE_INDEX]
                self.cur.execute(self.build_sub_select_query("point."+self.ID,"point join point_data on point.id=point_data.point_id","point.id = " + str(point_id) +" and wf_variable_id = "+ str(wf_variable_id)))
                id_count = len(self.cur.fetchall()[0])
                if id_count==0:
                    sql_code = "INSERT INTO " + self.TABLE + "(value, point_id, wf_variable_id) VALUES " + " (%s,%s,%s)"
                    self.cur.execute(sql_code,(read_dict[key][row_index],point_id,wf_variable_id))
                elif id_count==1:
                    sql_code = "UPDATE " + self.TABLE + " set " + "value=%s where point_id=%s and wf_variable_id =%s"
                    self.cur.execute(sql_code, (read_dict[key][row_index], point_id, wf_variable_id))
                else:
                    Exception("The point with id, "+point_id+" has more than one parent level attribute. This should be investigated.")
```

I am wondering the quickest way insert/update the data from my csv file. Should I run all my sub-queries first and store the results in a data structure? Similarly, once I find out if the query should be an insert or and update should I store these separately and run them using executemany() instead of using execute repeatedly or am I misunderstanding the purpose of executemany? 
As a side note, I realise that there are other improvements I could make to the code such as breaking the insert and update into separate functions, and I will refactor once I get this working, but for now I am just trying to address the issue of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this, I'll post what steps I took to improve efficiency. In general, the most important steps was minimising the number of calls to the postgres db.

I did some very basic profiling(ie put a time.time() at the top of my loop and then averaged a few iterations to try to figure out what parts were taking the longest). I found that removing even just a single SELECT from the loop cut a second off an average of a 5.6s loop(nearly a 20% savings). Clearly, the calls to the db are the dominating action. With that in mind I factored out the SELECTs as best as I could.

Since the first SELECT(the one used to find wf_variable_id)just looked up the variable id, I was able to store this in a list. I was batch updating the same set of variables, and the variable names were in the header of my csv, so I only needed to make this call one per variable, instead of for each row of my csv. I occasionally was updating the same point, so I stored these in a dict and first checked if my point id was in there before executing the SELECT and adding it to the dictionary(memory may be a limiting factor for other people viewing this post, but for me it was not). This shaved off roughly another second. So again, for anyone who stumbles upon this post, wherever possible remove queries and favour storing values in memory.

Comment: One final note, I refactored the loop so that it loops over everything I need to select in my csv and feeding it into a tuple. I then SELECTed all of these at once instead of one by one. This vastly improved performance. For example, on one test run of 500 lines, it took about 30 second to execute the single large query, as opposed to about 0.5 seconds per small query(totalling to 250s, or roughly 8x the amount of time.) Again the lesson is that minimising queries is key in speeding up scripts that use psychopg.